# Passing a pointer to a routine expecting an array of byte

Tags: delphi

I had code that compiled in Delphi 10.1 Berlin, but throws an error in Rio.

> "Incompatible types ByteArray and pointer.

The routine is defined with a single ByteArray parameter where
ByteArray is a type defined as

```
type ByteArray = array of byte;
```

Under 10.1 I could pass a pointer or @arrayname[0].
Under 10.3, it gives the Incompatible error above

```
interface

uses Windows, SysUtils, classes, Dialogs, Messages, Controls;

type
  ByteArray = array of byte;

procedure ArrayFunc(const P : ByteArray);
function TestFunction;

implementation

procedure ArrayFunc(const P : ByteArray);
begin    
  // code....    
end;

procedure TestFunction;    
var g : ByteArray;
begin    
  ArrayFunc(g); // works    
  Arrayfunc(@g[0]); // works under 10.1, not 10.3    
end;

end.
```

Comment: Please don't describe your code. Just show it here with necessary definitions.

Comment: I believe that code with **typed const parameter** cannot work in any Delphi version as written without type casting

Comment: @MBo, compiles in 10.1 but not in 10.2.

Comment: @LU RD Looks like compiler defect. I don't remember compiler options that allow such behavior

Comment: I'm astounded you don't consider `ArrayFunc(g)` to be the solution to your problem

Comment: As @David says, what is wrong with `ArrayFunc(g);`? Why do you want to pass a pointer to an open array parameter. Note that such a parameter requires two things to be passed: an address and a size (number of elements minus one). What is the array size if you pass a pointer to byte? If it works under 10.1, that is a bug. The 10.3 behaviour is correct.

Comment: If you put a statement to output the length of the open array parameter into *ArrayFunc* and compile and run that with 10.1 Berlin, what is the output? I don't have 10.1 Berlin installed here.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, its not an open array parameter. Read the confusion part of this article [Open array parameters and array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html). Don't forget to thank the author :-)

Comment: @LURD: Ah, yes, indeed, in this case it's a ByteArray, a dynarray type. I like the article, though. <g>

Comment: FWIW, I just entered this in Lazarus 2.0/FPC 3.0.4. It compiled! I'm flabbered and gasted and whatnot.

Answer (score 5):

This is a compiler defect that was fixed in Delphi 10.2

See [RSP 17511 E2010 Incompatible types for arrays and "Types @ operator"](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17511)

From QP:

> This is a deliberate change to Object Pascal. The problem is dynamic arrays are managed types, involving reference counting and associated helper function generation.
>
> Pointers generated from the @-operator with dynamic arrays bypasses the reference-counting mechanism which can and has lead to memory corruption.
>
> One can avoid this additional checking by an explicit typecasting as in this revised example.

```
type
  TMyRec = Record
    a,b : Integer ;
  end ;

var
  e : TArray<Integer>;
  f : TArray<TMyRec>;

procedure test;
var
  a : TArray<TMyRec>;
  b : TArray<TMyRec>;
  c : TArray<Integer>;
  d : TArray<Integer>;
begin
  SetLength( b, 2) ;
  b[0].a := 123 ;
  b[1].a := 345 ;
  a := TArray<TMyRec>(@b[0]);
  f := TArray<TMyRec>(@b[0]);
  a := TArray<TMyRec>(@b);
  a := TArray<TMyRec>(@f);
  a[0] := f[0] ;

  SetLength( c, 1) ;
  d := TArray<Integer>(@c);
  e := TArray<Integer>(@c);
end;
```

---

In your case, change

```
Arrayfunc(@g[0]);
```

to

```
Arrayfunc(ByteArray(@g[0]));
```

---

Be warned that you can't just pass any pointer to the `ArrayFunc` procedure. If the pointer does not point to a dynamic array, unexpected things can happen.

See this example that outputs the length zero instead of two:

```
Program TestDynArrPointer;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  ByteArray = array of byte;

procedure ArrayFunc( const arr : ByteArray);
begin
  WriteLn(Length(arr));  // Outputs zero length
end;

var
 arr : ByteArray;
begin
  SetLength(arr,2);
  ArrayFunc(ByteArray(@arr[1])); // <- Deliberately passing with an offset
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Er, do you really mean `Arrayfunc(ByteArray(@g[0]));`? Surely you mean `Arrayfunc(g);`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the whole point of the OP's question was to pass a raw pointer-to-dynamic-array to a dynamic array parameter. Certainly passing an actual dynamic array is technically the right solution, but that is not what is being asked for. So yes, to answer the question asked, the typecast is needed to satisfy the compiler and maintain dynamic array semantics.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But if you've got a dynamic array, then you can pass it, and if you don't have a dynamic array, then it's not safe to pass an untyped pointer. How do you end up with an untyped pointer if you know 100% for sure that what it points to is a dynamic array?

Comment: In the last example, just add `arr[0] := 200;` and then see the output. Length is not 0 anymore, but a negative number, -939524096 ($C8000000), instead. Note that $C8 = 200.

Comment: ,@David: you could of course mimic a dynarray, but I fail to see why anyone would do that. If you fool the compiler, you eventually fool yourself. <g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, yes that is what I meant with the example. If the pointer passed is not a correct pointer to a dynamic array, expect the unexpected.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I suppose that working with RTTI for example, would require use of pointers.

Comment: @LURD indeed. Bu if you have a true dynarray anyway, why would OP pass it as a raw pointer, instead of the dynarray you already have anyway? That makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the replies to my question. I understand now that passing  @g[0] is wrong and passing g on it's own should be done.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the replies to my question. Very much appreciated. I guess I will have to write an overloaded function that takes a pointer and then have it call ArrayFunc with an explicit typecast to ByteArray. One interesting thing I found is if I declare my arrayfunc as (Const P: array of byte) instead of (Const P ; ByteArray), it won't compile under any compiler. Once again, thanks for all the replies.